# WashOut::SOAP gem slow in rendering huge response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, rubygems, response

I have a an array of hash of arrays. 
render soap: { array_hash_return: response, status: { error_code: error_code, error_string: error_string } }

where response is an array of hash of arrays of almost about 1000 entries takes about 8 seconds to render the response.

Going through the gem files I dont see how I can spin a thread at the side to manually create the response and respond back or if there is a better way to create the soap response.